# Can I remove some of the guard dialogue?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For me and many others Skyrim is about immersion, and one of the things breaking that immersion are the idle chat from guards and other passing by NPCs.

What I'm talking about are comments such as

> Psst. Hey, I know who you are. Hail Sithis!

How did they know I was a part of this secret organization?

> Hey! You're the one who killed Alain Dufont, up in Raldbthar. Oh yeah, word about that got around. Man was a piece of bandit trash, is what I hear.

No-one saw me go in or out, and Alain was the only one to die there. You get the idea, hopefully. **I want these types of comments removed from the game.** No random NPC half way across Skyrim should ever be able to tell something I've done in secret. Mods are an option.

Comment: The best thing you can do is find a mod that removes it. I did a quick search and found this: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/23390/?. It doesn't do what you want, but it's supposed to improve immersion by unlocking many of the things guards can say.

Comment: @Grenyn You're probably right, but that particular mod doesn't help it. It specifically says it doesn't remove any dialogue. Besides, I've already been using it for a long time.

Comment: That's too bad then, I do understand your frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Dispensador](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/79470/dispensador) suggested, I created a mod that disables the dialogue lines. It is available for download at [Skyrim Nexus](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/58714/?) and disables all vanilla dialogue used by guards that gave me the feeling the guard knows I'm in the Dark Brotherhood when he (in my opinion) should not know it.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like this absolutely is possible, but it'll involve you making a mod which does this specifically. As you can see [here](http://skyrimforums.org/sf/threads/remove-dialogue-in-creation-kit.24391/) another person had a similar question about dialogue removal. It's clear that you'll have to use the Creation Kit to do this, basically changing the conditions it takes a piece of dialogue to be said.

> - Load up your mod in the CK and go to Edit>Find Text
> - You'll need to know the phrase you want to remove. Search for it or part of it. For example, I searched for the combat phrase "You dare
>     fight a dunmer?"
> - When you find the line, double-click. A new box will pop up showing lots of lines of dialog. Locate the phrase in the list and
>     double-click it.
> - In the area where it shows conditions for the dialog to be used, right-click and create a new condition. Copy these settings, except
>     change the Actor to the character you're working on.

The following picture should show you exactly what dialogue box you need to be fiddling with.
[image: Dialogue change]

Aside from this I do not think you are going to find more options for removing annoying dialogue.